# Keras multi GPU in vast.ai

Tags: deep-learning, keras, gpu, cloud-computing

I am trying to run a keras model on **vast.ai** using multiple GPUs. For that I am using **keras.utils.multi_gpu_model** , however I keep having this error:

```
if multi_GPU and n_GPUs > 1:
    model = multi_gpu_model(model)
```

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no
>   attribute 'experimental_list_devices')

I am using this default docker :

Official docker images for deep learning framework [TensorFlow](http://www.tensorflow.org)

> Successfully loaded tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-py3

I have also checked the available GPUs and all the GPUs are detected correctly:

Any ideas?

cheers

Comment: Can you include full code that produces this error, including imports?

Comment: **Solution:**

Finally I found the solution myself.  I just used another docker image with an older version of tensorflow (2.0.0), and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Finally I found the solution myself.  I just used another docker image with an older version of tensorflow (2.0.0), and the error disappeared.